# How to set alert message while object is null

Tags: javascript, object, null

There is a following loop, traversing through images:

When I type some items like `sky`, `day`, or `a`, or `b` it works but I want that when I type `akjfhhsh` or `23eewrr` or something that is not in object the code will show alert message, but it does not work.

```
images.forEach(image => {
    if (image !== null) {
        console.log(image);
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 img-item mb-2';
        div.innerHTML = ` <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" 
        onclick=selectItem(event,"${image.webformatURL}") src="${image.webformatURL}" 
        alt="${image.tags}">`;
        gallery.appendChild(div)
    }
    else {
        alert('Items not found');
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean `when I type something that is not in object` ?

Comment: in the code, images is an array and image is an object where image.tag is an object property suppose, now i want to check if search item is not found in the property, it will alert with an error message

Answer (score 0):

You can try next code

`if (image!==undefined)`

or just

`if (!image)`